# Integral being zero implies measure of set is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. How does
> $$\int_{E}e^{-x^2/2}dx=0.\tag{1}$$
> imply that the $m(E)=0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb{R}$.

This is a smaller part of a larger question, but I can't seem to see how it holds. Any help is appreciated.

I know that $(1)$ implies $f(x):=e^{-x^2/2}=0$ Lebesgue almost everywhere on $E$, since $f$ is a non-negative measurable function and $(1)$ holds.

Comment: @Théophile: Yes I did, fixed!

Comment: "I know that $(1)$ implies $f(x):=e^{-x^2/2}=0$ Lebesgue almost everywhere on $E$" - OK, so use this fact. You know that $f(x)$ is in fact **nowhere** zero, so the only way it can be zero almost everywhere in $E$ is if $E$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is sufficient to show that $m(E \cap [a, b]) = 0$ for every $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$. Let $t = \inf_{x \in [a, b]}{e^{-x^2/2}}$. Then $t > 0$ and we have
$$0 = \int_{E}e^{-x^2/2}dx \ge \int_{E\cap [a, b]}e^{-x^2/2}dx \ge \int_{E\cap [a, b]}tdx = m(E \cap [a, b])t$$ and as $t > 0$, this implies $m(E \cap [a, b]) = 0$.

Comment: Can you explain the first inequality (the one where you put in the $b$ value)?

Comment: Sorry, typed on my phone. Took me forever snd I did not see your answer...

Comment: From the graph of $e^{-x^2/2}$ this doesn't appear to hold, i.e. for values $x<0$. That is, the function appears to be increasing. Maybe I am confused?

Comment: Yes. I'd not taken negative values of $x$ into account. Does it look better now?

Comment: It does look correct, and a nice solution. Though, I'm not sure how/why it's  sufficient to show that $m(E\cap[a,b])=0$ for every $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$.

Comment: If $m(E \cap [a, b])> 0$ for some $a$ and $b$, then we'd have $m(E) \ge m(E \cap [a, b])> 0$.

Comment: Ah okay I see. So, why can't we just let $t:=\inf_{x\in E}e^{-x^2/2}$? It would still be the case that $t>0$ and we'd get the inequality so that $0\geq m(E)t$.

Comment: You wouldn't have $t > 0$, if $E$ was not bounded above.

Comment: So for example if $E:=(0,+\infty)$ then $t\ngtr0$, for the $t$ that I defined?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Thank you, accepted the answer now!